# When to do validation when we are training based off of training steps?

Tags: validation, machine-learning, neural-network, training-data

Sorry if this question seems a bit odd and perhaps basic, but as I have been unfortunate in finding an answer to it, I decided to ask it here.

I know that in the context of deep neural networks, we validate the trained model on the validation (i.e., development) set after completion of *each training epoch*, which means simply after going over all the training data points once. I also know the differences between the concepts: *epoch*, *training step*, and *batch size*, as well as the relation between them which people often get to mix up.

My question now is that when we train the neural network based on the training steps (suppose we would like to proceed training loops considering the training steps, which is a pre-defined hyperparameter of the model ––and not epochs), when should we validate the model on the validation set? Do we still (just) need to consider/compute epochs to figure out the right time (step) to perform the validation?

And another question; is it a reasonable practice if we validate the model on the validation set after completion of a *fixed number* of training steps? Say, the total training steps that we want to train is 50,000 steps, and we validate the model after each 5000 steps interval.

Comment: Using some kind of log interval, as you described, seems to be a fairly standard. For example, check out this kaggle uNet implementation: https://www.kaggle.com/witwitchayakarn/u-net-with-pytorch. Even though there is an Epoch loop, the creator decided to log on a fixed interval instead.
Unorthodox but from my experience this kind of thing is considered acceptable in an academic context.

Comment: Interesting, @Joshua! Thanks! I'm now wondering if that does make any difference in model performance when using *fixed interval* for tuning the model on validation set instead of using *epochs*. B.c. what makes me picky about this is that I have seen most people using *epoch* intervals for tuninig... tho it's good to see this link on your behalf which made me less picky. Thanks!